# How to know which iteration is the last line at foreach File.ReadLines

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, .net-4.5

How to know which iteration is the last line at foreach File.ReadLines

Here example loop

```
foreach (var vrLine in File.ReadLines(vrItem))
{

}
```

I want to use ReadLines because some files have millions of lines

However i also need to know the last iteration

Thank you

c# .net 4.5.2 c# 5

Comment: why do u want to know the last line?

Comment: @DarthVader i want to know which iteration is the last one. So i can do some events before it exists from foreach loop

Comment: Why is it important that handling the last line be inside the loop?

Comment: Exactly, it will cost performance.

Comment: Why do you need to do some event inside the loop?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG What is your use case where you can't raise your events *after* the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something as follows:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(vrItem);

var last = lines.LastorDefault();

foreach(var line in lines){

}
```

This would give you the last line if there is. However, if the collection is huge, in order to get the last one, you will iterate the collection, which will cost you performance.

You can also do it in place without using LastorDefault, as follows:

```
string lastLine = string.Empty;
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines()){


   lastLine = line;
}

// Here you have last line, ultimately in one run. 
// However, here you are out of the loop. Not sure if this is what you want.
```

An old fashion way would be :

```
int i;

var lines = File.ReadLines(vrItem);
var linecount = lines.Count();

for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++) {

     if (i == linecount - 1) {
           // this is the last item
     }
}
```

But then again, for very large files, Count is eager so it will iterate through the collection. This is also expensive.

Comment: hmm this seems like a good solution do you think this is performance wise ?

Comment: thank you so the real answer is there is no way to know which iteration is the last iteration inside foreach loop right ?

Comment: Doesn't `File.ReadLines` return an `IEnumerable<string>`? Don't think `Count` and indexers will work.

Comment: There is a linq extension for `Count()`. but again, this is irrelevant right now. we are not interested in `Count` as it will have performance drawbacks.

Comment: It will be better if you declare one int variable which will be assigned to `lines.Count` in outside of for loop in "old fashioned way".

Comment: Ok, but now to get the actual line, you have to use `ElementAt`, which might be suboptimal.

Comment: You should probably just do `File.ReadLines(vrItem).ToArray()`.

Comment: I got the point that there is no way to determine which iteration inside foreach is the last one am i correct ?

Comment: Well there is but for very large files, it is expensive.

Comment: You might also wanna use streaming for very large files.

Comment: @DarthVader non of your solutions find inside foreach loop which iteration is the latest how there is a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the last line via LastorDefault() beforehand is not good, performance-wise because it will iterate over the whole collection to find the last item. Therefore, you enumerate the IEnumerable twice.

However, you can forgo the foreach loop and use the iterator manually and avoid this cost. Something like:

```
using (var enumerator = File.ReadLines().GetEnumerator())
{
    enumerator.MoveNext(); // TODO: Check result
    var current = enumerator.Current;
    while(true)
    {
        if(enumerator.MoveNext())
            // current is a Normal item
        else
        {
            // current is the last item
            // do your special thing and then exit the loop
            break;
        }
        current = enumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

You may need to to some more error checking for empty collections and collections with only one item.